# Phonegap/Cordova with Multiple CDVViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, uiviewcontroller

my Idea is to use Phonegap for the business logic of my app, but use native transitions. So I need CDVWebView in every UIViewController. This works fine with normal UIWebviews, but if I use multiple CDVViewControllers for e.g. a TabBar, the deviceReady event only fires for the first CDVWebView.

Here is what I do in the App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    
NSURL* url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
NSString* invokeString = nil;

if (url && [url isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
    invokeString = [url absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"NativeNavigationTest launchOptions = %@", url);
}    
NSLog(@"invokeString = %@", invokeString);
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

CGRect viewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];


//4 ViewController, each one inherits from CDVViewController

self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;
self.viewController.view.frame = viewBounds;

self.secondController = [[[SecondController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.secondController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.secondController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.secondController.startPage = @"second.html";
self.secondController.invokeString = invokeString;
self.secondController.view.frame = viewBounds;


self.thirdController = [[[ThirdController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.thirdController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.thirdController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.thirdController.startPage = @"third.html";
self.thirdController.invokeString = invokeString;
self.thirdController.view.frame = viewBounds;

self.fourthController = [[[FourthController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.fourthController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.fourthController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.fourthController.startPage = @"fourth.html";
self.fourthController.invokeString = invokeString;
self.fourthController.view.frame = viewBounds;


//add them in a native ViewController environment like a Tabbar

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, secondController, thirdController, fourthController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

This is the error I get for each ViewController except for the first.

```
Error: executing module function 'setInfo' in module 'cordova/plugin/ios/device'. Have you included the iOS version of the cordova-1.9.0.js
```

and

```
ERROR: Attempting to call cordova.exec() before 'deviceready'. Ignoring.
```

Of course I refer to cordova-1.9.0 in my HTML files, I think Cordova was not designed to use multiple WebViews of it, but does anybody know how to change this?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Cordova and have reported it in their issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2271

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is [Cordova WebView](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html). Designed to be embedded in native Applications.

**edit**

with Multiple Cordova Webviews, it has the same errors. I don´t know what´s the point of it when you can still only put one single Phonegap powered Webview in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed this as a [race condition in Cordova](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2271) - the issue is fixed as of 2.4.0.