# Multiple CordovaWebviews, cordova.exec defined in one but not in the other

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an iOS project that utilizes multiple CordovaWebviews (CDDViewControllers) and for some reason cordova.exec is defined in the main webview (index.html), but not in the other webviews. Has anyone run across this problem? Is there any reason why having multiple Cordova enabled webviews would alter the cordova global variable like that?

I'm using Cordova 2.2.0rc2 and this wasn't an issue in 2.1.0

Comment: Hi Mark Nutter. I think I´m using your GCM Plugin, great job on that. To your question: It seems like phonegap offers a solution for it, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082330/phonegap-cordova-with-multiple-cdvviewcontroller